# How to say that you know someone but without telling what is the relationship between you?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say that someone and some other person are both know each other, but without exposing the relationship between them.
I found that all the words are with a "taste" about the relationship.

For example, you can say they both friends, acquaintances, buddies etc. But every choice will have some taste. And it is not necessarily true that they both friend, acquaintances etc.

I don't want to say Alice and Bob are both know each other. It is wordy and it giving the feeling like I have something to hide, which is partly true but I don't want to give this feeling.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Even if you *were* to consider saying *Alice and Bob **know each other*** (forget ungrammatical ***are*** and unnecessary ***both*** there), that wouldn't be exactly "neutral". For instance, if you did use that form, I might think "Why didn't he write *know **of** each other* there?" I just don't see how it makes sense to identify people as "mutual acquaintances" whilst trying to obfuscate or keep secret the nature of the circumstances whereby they come to be in that situation.

Comment: "I am aware of that individual."

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "Alice and Bob know each other" or even just "Alice knows Bob" which kind of implies that Bob knows Alice too. I wouldn't say "know of" because that doesn't mean the same thing. I *know of* Queen Elizabeth, but she doesn't know of me, and we don't *know* each other, we've never met.

Comment: I also don't see anything wrong with "Alice and Bob have met," which has no connotation that I could point to, or "Alice and Bob are acquainted," which is a little more formal but still just implies that they have met.

Comment: I want to help people arrange some information, so I want to be able to put in the same category father and son relation together with classmates.
All I care about in this category is that they know each other.
It feels to me a bit odd to say it that way.